# Ruby: dump YAML with sorted keys

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have some data which I need to save into a yaml file in Ruby. However I need the output to be consistent so I need the keys in the yaml to be sorted alphabetically.

The Psych implementation has no option for sorting keys. So far I was unable to find any good workaround.

Also I need it to be reasonably fast since I'm dealing with relatively large data (10k-200k lines).

Comment: You can sort top-level keys easily. There's no built-in mechanism for sorting nested keys. Please show some example inputs, the code you've tried, and your expected output.

Comment: Sorting just top-level keys is completely useless for me. As for example input and expected output see https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/sort-keys#sort-keys-recursively. I didn't try any code yet.

Comment: I don't know how you generate the YAML file, but in a typical approach, you prepare a Ruby Hash and convert this into YAML. Since Ruby Hashes maintain the insertion order, you just need to put the keys into the Hash in sorted order.

Comment: It's not Hash but rather a structure of custom classes. I have to use `YAML::unsafe_load()` when loading it.

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to sort a nested hash before dumping it to YAML? Or how to load an already sorted YAML into Ruby while keeping the order? Or how to avoid using `unsafe_load` when dealing with custom classes?

Comment: How to dump my structure into a sorted YAML of if that's impossible how to sort the  YAML after dumping it. Custom classes are only mentioned here to clarify that I don't have a structure of Hash instances that I could sort before dumping.